# detecting seasonality in R for daily data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a simple tibble `TIB` containing a date and measure of phenomenon (let's say, website traffic received on that date):

```
     dmy          traffic
 1 2019-01-29   0.6
 2 2019-01-30   0.7
 3 2019-01-31   0.7
 4 2019-02-01   0.8
 5 2019-02-02   0.8
 6 2019-02-03   0.8
 7 2019-02-04   0.7
 8 2019-02-05   0.7
...
```

This includes a total of 400+ observations (about 1.5 years of data).

I convert it into time series object:

```
TSTIB<-ts(as.data.frame(TIB))
```

I now would like to find if there is some periodicity/seasonality in this set of data. How do I do it in R? Specifically, I am trying to figure out if there are spikes or drops in traffic occurring every X times, and the value of X.

I tried `findfrequency(TSTIB)` and it gives me 1, but I am not sure how to interpret it or if this is even correct.

I also ran `spectrum(TSTIB)` and for some reason it gives me this message:

> In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log, recycle = TRUE) :   240
>   y values <= 0 omitted from logarithmic plot

even though I do not have any 0 values in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use decompose. When you plot it, you can see the observed time series, trend, seasonal component and random nicely. You can access the seasonal data using $seasonal.

```
TSTIB.decomp <- decompose(TSTIB)
plot(TSTIB.decomp)
TSTIB.decomp$seasonal
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried- I am getting error message "Error in decompose(TSTIB) : time series has no or less than 2 periods.

Comment: I added frequency=7 to ts() function,and that seemed to solve the problem - at least i am getting decomposition